# Dell R210 & FreeBSD

Tags: unix, installation, freebsd, dell

I'm trying to get FreeBSD installed on a Dell R210 server with the H200 hard drive controller.  I can boot with the 8.2-RELEASE ISO and the 8-STABLE-20110522 ISO.  My problem is getting it to boot from the internal HDs.

It seems that I need a driver in the 8-STABLE branch (not in 8.2-RELEASE) in order to use the disks as da0 and da1.  It doesn't work with them in a RAID-1 configuration at all, unfortunately.  So I booted from the 8-STABLE-20110522 disk and can install with it.  However, I think that I can only install official releases, not from the stable branch.

So...

1) Am I wrong?  Is there a way to install 8-STABLE while booted from that DVD?

2) Is there a way to cvsup/makeworld the internal drive while booted from a DVD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can install STABLE branch (unless installer is broken).You can install it even if installer is broken. You need to run `install.sh` scripts in appropriate sub-directories of `8-STABLE` directory in root of DVD (base & kernels is minimal set) with `DESTDIR` param pointing to your HDD.
2. You can extract FreeBSD source to your HDD by using `install.sh DESTDIR=/mnt/yourhdd` in `./8-STABLE/src`. After that you can building world with `make buildworld` and finally installing with `make installworld DISTDIR=/mnt/yourhdd`